# Custom listing posts by category and nr. of posts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

hope someone can give me idea of how i can accomplishe what im trying to do. Basically i need to list records from the database, more specically news posts, but i need to list the posts as groups of 6 by category alternately, where first post is the featured post.

I need to query by category, and after getting the posts from this category i need to group by 6 posts where first one is the featured (each post have a column that identifies what category or if feature is true or false.

So i imagine first creating in my Category model a method called posts:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

So than i n my controller, for example home page i can do like:

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

And than in my view blade i can do:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->posts() as $post)
        {{$post->title}}
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

So now i need to group in each category in 6 posts where the first one is the featured post of this category. 
Final Result Schema:(ex: Total categories are 4 (A,B,C,D))

````
```
Category A
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

Category B
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

Category C
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

Category D
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

Category A
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

Category B
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

Category C
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

Category D
Feature Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post | Normal Post

....
````

Can someone give a hint how i could do that?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to either change the relationship or create a new one

```
public function latestPosts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->orderBy('featured')->take(6);
}
```

But here, you have to make sure each category only has ONE featured post. If a category has more than 1 feature post, all the future post will come first.

Doing

```
$category->latestPosts()
```

Will give you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering your question:**

Create a method in your `Category` model called `postsChunck`:

```
public function postsChunck() 
{

    return $this->posts()->orderBy('is_featured', 'DESC')->limit(6)->get();

}
```

This method will:

- query for all the posts for the category;
- order them by the `is_featured` column. This should show the featured ones first, since boolean values in a (MySql) database are stored as 0 or 1;
- get only the first 6 results from the query.

In your code you will use this method as such:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->postsChunck() as $post)
        {{$post->title}}
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

**Recomendation**

When querying the categories, you should eager load its posts and while doing that, constraint the amount of posts that are loaded. This will reduce the amount of queries needed to execute to get the posts for each category.

```
$categories = Category::with(['posts' => function ($query) {

    $query->orderBy('is_featured', 'DESC')->limit(6);

}])->get();
```

And then you will have your usual code in your view:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->posts as $post)
        {{$post->title}}
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

With the difference that we are not using the method `posts`, but the magic property `posts`, that was eager loaded with the posts data earlier.

Answer (score 0):

First, start by [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the posts so you're not running into an n+1 issue running that related query for each loop in your view.

```
$categories = Category::with('posts')->get();
```

Then in your view you can chunk the results and use the [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable) variable to check for featured like:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @php
        $featuredPost = $category->posts->first(function($post) {
            return $post->featured;
        });
    @endphp
    <h1>{{$featuredPost->title}}</h1>
    <h2>FEATURED POST!</h2>
    @foreach ($category->posts->where('featured', false)->chunk(5) as $post)
        <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
        <h2>Not SO FEATURED POST!</h2>
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Comment: But in the featured post before it must be organiized since each post haves a column that says wich post is featured (1,0). With the example you gave me how is set it?

Comment: Gotcha, I didn't catch that part.  I have updated it to reflect the feature post first and then the next 5 would not be the featured post for that category.